# Eclipse Plugin with GitHub

Tags: java, github, slf4j

I am trying to check out `SLF4J-Simple` from [GitHub](https://github.com/ceki/slf4j) which shows the actual source repository at:

> https://github.com/ceki/slf4j.git

I would like to check this directly out of the repo and import it into a new Eclipse project. I *do not* want to just download the ZIP or get at the source.

I am trying to change some of the `slf4j-simple` code and repackage it into a different JAR per the instructions on SLF4J's site.

I've never used GitHub before and was wondering what Eclipse plugins were preferential. I currently have Subversive installed for SVN and am quite comfortable with it. Just looking for something that "gets the job done" and will allow full import from the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/)** is the official Eclipse plugin to use, allowing you to define a remote reference to your GitHub project and to pull the repo.

EGit is now included with the latest Eclipse distributions and/or can be installed [through MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1336).

See [Vogella's tutorial "Git with EGit"](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html) for an example of GitHub project pulled in your Eclipse workspace.
Here is an example where you would push, but you get the same kind of parameters to clone or pull a git repo:

[image: Egit parameters]

Comment: For the parameters needed to clone a remote repo, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Cloning_remote_Repositories

Comment: Another technique to link a remote GitHub project to Eclipse workspace (still with EGit): http://blogspot.makotokw.com/2010/01/05/how-to-clone-git-project-form-github-by-using-egit-on-windows-sygwin/

Comment: Thanks VonC - however upon cloning SLF4J to my workspace I am getting some bizarre behavior in Eclipse. My file system sees that slf4j/ is located inside my Eclipse's workspace/ directory; however Eclipse does not see it as a project!! I did get a warning message stating that my HOME env var was not set. Could that have had anything to do with it? Whats the trick to seeing the clone inside package/project explorer? Thanks again!

Comment: @zharvey `HOME` is used by EGit, mainly for ssh key storage. As for your project, once cloned, you can try and "import an existing project in your workspace". Or you can try again from scratch, following http://blogspot.makotokw.com/2010/01/05/how-to-clone-git-project-form-github-by-using-egit-on-windows-sygwin/